# Nginx wont send POST to FastCGI backend, but GET works fine?

Tags: nginx, http, fastcgi, mercurial

Not sure why, but it is happy sending a GET to the FastCGI backend (Mercurial hgwebdir in this case), but simply resorts to the filesystem if the request is a POST.

Relevant parts of `nginx.conf`:

```
    location / {
        root /var/www/htdocs/;
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /hg {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hg-fastcgi.socket;
        include fastcgi_params;

        if ($request_uri ~ ^/hg([^?#]*)) {
            set $rewritten_uri $1;
        }

        limit_except GET {
            allow all;
            deny all;

            auth_basic "hg secured repos";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/trac.htpasswd;
        }

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "/hg";
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $rewritten_uri;

        # for authentication
        fastcgi_param AUTH_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;

        #fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
        #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

GET's work fine, but POST delivers this error to the error_log:

```
2010/05/17 14:12:27 [error] 18736#0: *1601 open() "/usr/html/hg/test" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: domain.com, request: "POST /hg/test HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

What could possibly be the issue?  I'm trying to allow read-only access via GET's to the page, but require authorization when using `hg push` to the same url which sends a POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone gets dug into the hole I did, here is how I dug out:

```
    location /hg {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hg-fastcgi.socket;
        include fastcgi_params;

        if ($request_uri ~ ^/hg([^?#]*)) {
            set $rewritten_uri $1;
        }
        rewrite ^/hg$ /hg/ redirect;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "/hg";
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $rewritten_uri;

        # for authentication
        fastcgi_param AUTH_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 401 = @hgauth;
    }

    location @hgauth {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hg-fastcgi.socket;
        include fastcgi_params;

        if ($request_uri ~ ^/hg([^?#]*)) {
            set $rewritten_uri $1;
        }   
        auth_basic "hg secured repos";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/trac.htpasswd;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "/hg";
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $rewritten_uri;

        # for authentication
        fastcgi_param AUTH_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    }
```

The important part is `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;`, `error_page 401 = @hgauth;`, and using `location @hgauth {`.  I'm not sure it's possible to do this any other way.  Please let me know if this answer helped!

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in nginx which was fixed in [0.8.48](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES).

BTW, you have to use `fastcgi_split_path_info` as `if` does not get triggered correctly with `limit_except`.

So at the end something like that should work for you:

```
location /hg {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hg-fastcgi.socket;
    include fastcgi_params;

    limit_except GET HEAD {
        auth_basic "hg secured repos";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/trac.htpasswd;
    }

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/hg)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

    # for authentication
    fastcgi_param AUTH_USER $remote_user;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback.  I will definitely be trying this out.